# How to create a dropdownlist from an XML file?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, drop-down-menu

I've been told it's possible with HTML potentially using...

```
 <select> element with <option children>
```

And also in order to get the value of an attribute to use this code its possible to use...

```
elementNode.attributes.item(0).nodeValue
```

Here is XML file format I need to extract country and rate from..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<exchangeRates>
<rate country="aud" >0.97</rate>
<rate country="usd" >1.01</rate>
</exchangeRates>
```

I need for the dropdownlist to show country and the rate exactly like this..

```
aud    0.97
usd    1.01
```

I'm really struggling. I tried doing in asp.net, but the dropdownlist will only show one value (aud, usd).

Once the lists are working, I need it to say by default "current rates" and have this not appear again when list is shown. Also a tabindex 1 or 2 so it's not selected by default.

Any helps/tips much appreciated!!

Comment: So you want a select like the following?


`<select>

<option value="0.97">oud&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0.97</option>

<option value="1.01">usd&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1.01</option>

</select>`

Comment: if it works, i want anything :D

Comment: So lets get this right. You are supplied an xml file full of exchange rates in the format you stated above (you have no control over this format?). And you need the dropdownlist that displays the country and rate ([country] [rate]) and has the value set to the rate.

Comment: Yes, the xml file is in that format and can't be changed. And yes I need a dropdownlist showing just those two things in an .aspx file preferably. Also to get it to show "current rates" by default and once list loads, for "current rates" to never appear again. Any help is greatly appreciated!! :D

Comment: Next time, please don't add ‘help!’ et al. to your question (title). We already know you want our help, otherwise you wouldn't ask a question here. BTW, what do you want exactly? You want to do it in JavaScript but write to an .aspx file? You actually know the difference between server-side and client-side scripting?

Comment: You can de-serialise the xml into an object with the same structure + a `displayvalue` property. This new property can return the country and rate as a concatenated string. Then bind the dropdownlist to ``value`` and ``displayvalue``

Comment: Marcel, sorry but it's been frustrating me. And Ollie, how do I de-serialise it exactly (code)? Sounds interesting..

Answer (score 0):

You could use XSLT to transform the XML to a HTML dropdown.
Here is the javascript:

```
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send("");
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
xml=loadXMLDoc("rates.xml");
xsl=loadXMLDoc("dropdown.xsl");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=ex;
  }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("example").appendChild(resultDocument);
```

Where rates.xml is your xml file full of rates, like above.

Where dropdown.xsl is your xsl transform file:

```
  <select>
      <xsl:for-each select="exchangeRates/rate">
     <option><xsl:value-of select="@country" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<xsl:value-of select="." /></option>
      </xsl:for-each>
 </select

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```